# Cannot upload apk to lg g5 through Android SDK

Tags: sdk, android-developer-api

Previously I would just attach my Samsung Note 4 to my computer, have it in developer mode, APK uploaded from the SDK, no problem. I got a LG G5, developer mode on, allow installation from apps from sources other than Google Play Store, on, result?

```
$ adb push C:\Users\me\AndroidStudioProjects\ThisProject\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.this.project
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.this.project"
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?


$ adb shell pm uninstall com.this.project
Unknown failure (Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?)
Error while Installing APK
```

What I can do is email myself an APK, open it in my gmail app in my phone, download and install it, which is not the way I would like to debug my APKs. I'm missing a setting or configuration here, just not sure what it is yet, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of head scratching I just went nuts, I kept changing the way the phone connected to the pc from file transfer, to charging, to power supply, to photo transfer, when I got to photo transfer it accepted the apk, suddenly the package manager was paying attention. Oddly enough it is now paying attention to the SDK in the previous settings as well now. No idea why, just glad that it works.